# How to embed the Oracle OleDb drivers into a C# project

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, deployment, oledb

I have a C# .NET project that connects to an Oracle RAC using the Oracle OleDb drivers. I can't remember why we decided to use the Oracle drivers a couple of years ago, but I think it had to do with the .NET adapters not supporting the type of connection string we needed to use or something. Anyways, regardless of why, we are using them now, and I am trying to find a way to embed those drivers into my project without having to install the drivers on the target production environment. I am sure I read an article on this before, but my Google-fu is failig me, and I can't seem to find the article again. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I found it. This is what I was looking for.

http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=232